# Not sure why this pattern guard matches

Tags: haskell, pattern-guards

Learning Haskell and I am not sure why I don't get the expected result, given these definitions:

```
instance Ring Integer where
  addId  = 0
  addInv = negate
  mulId  = 1

  add = (+)
  mul = (*)

class Ring a where
  addId  :: a            -- additive identity
  addInv :: a -> a       -- additive inverse
  mulId  :: a            -- multiplicative identity

  add :: a -> a -> a     -- addition
  mul :: a -> a -> a     -- multiplication
```

I wrote this function

```
squashMul :: (Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMul x y
  | (Lit mulId) <- x = y
  | (Lit mulId) <- y = x
squashMul x y = Mul x y
```

However:

```
*HW05> squashMul (Lit 5) (Lit 1)
Lit 1
```

If I write one version specifically for Integer:

```
squashMulInt :: RingExpr Integer -> RingExpr Integer -> RingExpr Integer
squashMulInt x y
  | (Lit 1) <- x = y
  | (Lit 1) <- y = x
squashMulInt x y = Mul x y
```

Then I get the expected result.

Why does `(Lit mulId) <- x` match even when x is not (Lit 1) ?

Comment: `mulId` is a new local variable, unrelated to the previously defined one. You want `Lit w <- x , w==mulId = ...` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables used in pattern matching are considered to be local variables. Consider this definition for computing the length of a list:

```
len (x:xs) = 1 + len xs
len _      = 0
```

Variables `x` and `xs` are local variables to this definition. In particular, if we add a definition for a top-level variable, as in

```
x = 10
len (x:xs) = 1 + len xs
len _      = 0
```

this does *not* affect the meaning for `len`. More in detail, the first pattern `(x:xs)` is *not* equivalent to `(10:xs)`. If it were interpreted in that way, we would now have `len [5,6] == 0`, breaking the previous code! Fortunately, the semantics of pattern matching is robust to such new declarations as `x=10`.

Your code

```
squashMul :: (Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMul x y
  | (Lit mulId) <- x = y
  | (Lit mulId) <- y = x
squashMul x y = Mul x y
```

actually means

```
squashMul :: (Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMul x y
  | (Lit w) <- x = y
  | (Lit w) <- y = x
squashMul x y = Mul x y
```

which is wrong, since `w` can be arbitrary. What you want is probably:

```
squashMul :: (Eq a, Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMul x y
  | (Lit w) <- x , w == mulId = y
  | (Lit w) <- y , w == mulId = x
squashMul x y = Mul x y
```

(The `Eq a` constraint may depend on the definition of `RingExpr`, which was not posted)

You can also simplify everything to:

```
squashMul :: (Eq a, Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMul x@(Lit w) y         | w == mulId = y
squashMul x         y@(Lit w) | w == mulId = x
squashMul x         y                      = Mul x y
```

or even to:

```
squashMul :: (Eq a, Ring a) => RingExpr a -> RingExpr a -> RingExpr a
squashMul (Lit w) y       | w == mulId = y
squashMul x       (Lit w) | w == mulId = x
squashMul x       y                    = Mul x y
```

This version does not even use pattern guards, since there's no need to.

Comment: Thanks! On the last note, "you can also simplify" - on what basis is it simpler? only in that it does not use pattern guards? or, perhaps it is more idiomatic to avoid pattern guards if possible?

Comment: @j-a Pattern guards are a GHC extension of Haskell, which is useful when you need to write e.g. `f x y | Just z <- g (x+y) = ...` where there's a complex expression on the right of `<-`. When using instead `pattern <- x`, the standard `x@pattern` construct suffices. The latter is also more idiomatic. Which one is actually simpler is of course a matter of taste.

Comment: thx, is there any particular reason why you used x@.. even though not required? squashMul x@(Lit w) y         | w == mulId = y => squashMul (Lit w) y         | w == mulId = y